# How to apply same operation to multiple data frames in dplyr-R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyverse

I would like to apply the same operation to multiple data frames in 'R' but cannot get how to deal with this matter.

This is an example of `pipe` operation in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

    iris %>% mutate(Sepal=rowSums(select(.,starts_with("Sepal"))),
                    Length=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Length"))),
                    Width=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Width"))))
iris2 <- iris
iris3 <- iris
```

Could you suggest how to apply the same pipe function to `iris`, `iris2` and `isis3`? I need to use `dplyr` piping operation.

I suppose `map` function may help but as I have not fully understand its concept, I got errors to apply it.

Sample script:

```
library(purrr)

iris.set <- c(iris,iris2,iris3)
map(iris.set, ~ . %>% mutate(Sepal=rowSums(select(.,starts_with("Sepal"))),
                Length=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Length"))),
                Width=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Width")))))
```

Comment: Make the following changes: `iris.set <- list(iris,iris2,iris3)`
`map(iris.set, ~ .x %>% mutate(Sepal=rowSums(select(.,starts_with("Sepal"))),
                Length=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Length"))),
                Width=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Width")))))`

Comment: @CPak Great! So I need to unlist `iris.set` if I need to keep those data frames individually?

Comment: What do you mean keep them individually?

Comment: I mean that the resulted list contains 3 data frames, `iris`, `iris2` and `iris3`. I need them back to 3 data frames again stored in `data.frame`, not `list`.
I created new post for this specific issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860018/how-to-split-data-frames-in-a-list-into-multiple-data-frames-in-r

Answer (score 11):

If you turn your operation into a function:

```
library(dplyr)
my_fun <- function(x) { 
      x %>%       
          mutate(Sepal=rowSums(select(.,starts_with("Sepal"))),
          Length=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Length"))),
          Width=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Width"))))
}
```

You can pipe a list of data frames to it easily:

```
result <- list( iris, iris2, iris3 ) %>%
    lapply( my_fun )
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I prefer to keep using `dplyr` for easy operation as suggested by @www.

Comment: Hi @rosscova - any way I can replace the existing 'iris' dataframes instead of combining them into 'result'?

Answer (score 1):

is it good for you ?

```
    library(dplyr)

    #matrices replication 
    iris1=iris
    iris2=iris
    iris3=iris

    #list of combinations: apply is tricky for array input
    irises=matrix(c("iris1","iris2","iris3"), ncol=1)

    #function design
    Funct<-function(df_name){

      df=get(df_name)
      df %>% mutate(Sepal=rowSums(select(.,starts_with("Sepal"))),
                    Length=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Length"))),
                    Width=rowSums(select(.,ends_with("Width"))))
    }

    apply(irises,MARGIN=2, Funct)
```

Comment: This is returning an error: Error in get(df_name) : first argument has length > 1